# How to customize form field by choosing dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

If I select "Chrome" then only two form fields should appear. If I select Firefox then 3 form fields should appear & likewise. How can i do so?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>helo</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" placeholder="Select" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
<br><br>
<label>Title </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="title"> <br><br>
<label>Sub title </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="subtitle"> <br><br>
<label>Developed by </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="developer"> <br><br>
<label>Organization </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="organization"> <br><br>
<label>Description </label> &nbsp;<input type="textarea" name="description"> <br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Which fields should appear when certain options are selected?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gerard Sir i want if I chose a dropdown list then some of the form fields will appear and other get hidden. For example- If I chose "Chrome" then only Title, Organization & Description fields will appear and other fields get hidden.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. We can help you if you're stuck with your existing code, but we won't write it all for you. Currently, this question is too broad and unspecific.

Comment: I have tried this but all the field get hidden or shown on choosing any drop down. Given a onchange="populate(this.id,'slct') in dropdown and written this javasctipt    <script>
  function populate(s1) {
   var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);

   if(s1.value == "chrome"){
    document.getElementById('fields').style.display='none';
   }
   if(s1.value == "Firefox"){
    document.getElementById('fields').style.display='block';
   }

  }
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for the chrome selection. You can expand further for the other browsers. Documentation in the source.

```js
const selected = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
selected.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const browser = selected.value;
  
  /* Create an array with all elements having class = input */
  const allFields = [...document.getElementsByClassName("input")];
  /* Hide all fields */
  allFields.map(field => field.style.display = "none");
  
  /* Show the fields depending on browser selection */
  switch (browser.toLowerCase()) {
    case "chrome":
      /* Title, Organization & Description */
      document.getElementById("title").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("organization").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("description").style.display = "block";
      break;
    case "firefox":
      break;
    default:
      /* Any code that should run if no browser matches */
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0; /* White space at bottom */
}
```

```html
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" placeholder="Select" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
<br><br>
<div id="title" class="input">
  <label>Title </label><input type="text" name="title">
</div>
<div id="subtitle" class="input">
  <label>Sub title </label><input type="text" name="subtitle">
</div>
<div id="developed" class="input">
  <label>Developed by </label><input type="text" name="developer">
</div>
<div id="organization" class="input">
  <label>Organization </label><input type="text" name="organization">
</div>
<div id="description" class="input">
  <label>Description </label><input type="textarea" name="description">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jQuery. All fields are displayed at first and then fields are filtered depending on the "data-filter" attribute values. Filter happens on "change", so you must press enter or leave the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="myBrowser"').on('change', filterInputFields);
  
  function filterInputFields() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    $('.inputFields li').each(function() {
   
      var filterValue = $(this).data('filter');
      
      if (filterValue.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>helo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" placeholder="Select" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
<br><br>
<ul class="inputFields">
  <li data-filter="Chrome,Firefox"><label>Title </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="title"> </li>
  <li data-filter="Chrome,Firefox"><label>Sub title </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="subtitle"> </li>
  <li data-filter="Opera,Firefox"><label>Developed by </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="developer"> </li>
  <li data-filter="Internet Explorer"><label>Organization </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="organization"> </li>
  <li data-filter="Internet Explorer"><label>Description </label> &nbsp;<input type="textarea" name="description"></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, you've solved my big problem. It totally works for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using jQuery and classes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>helo</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" placeholder="Select" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
<br><br>
<div class="input chrome firefox">
    <label>Title </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="title"> <br><br>
</div>
<div class="input  firefox opera internet_explorer">
    <label>Sub title </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="subtitle"> <br><br>
</div>
<div class="input  firefox opera safari internet_explorer">
    <label>Developed by </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="developer"> <br><br>
</div>
<div class="input chrome opera safari internet_explorer">
    <label>Organization </label> &nbsp;<input type="text" name="organization"> <br><br>
</div>
<div class="input chrome firefox opera safari internet_explorer">
    <label>Description </label> &nbsp;<input type="textarea" name="description"> <br><br>
</div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name=myBrowser]").on("change", function() {
            var class_name = $(this).val().replace(" ", "_").toLowerCase();
            $(".input").hide();
            $("." + class_name).show();

        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much once again.